# Clarification about first spherical harmonic

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spherical-harmonics

If the quantum numer $l$ is equal to zero, each components of **L** has eigenvalues $m=0$. So the states that have $l=0$ are simulaneous eigenvectors of each components of L. But, my textbook says, it is not a problem, because states with 0-angular momentum aren't a complete set of states.

Please, could you explain me the reason of the last sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the operators:

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&-1 \end{array} \right)$$

$$B=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
0&1&0 \end{array} \right)$$

then $[A,B]\neq 0$ but they share a common eigenvector

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \end{array} \right)$$

There's no problem. What you might be worrried about would be a contradiction of the uncertainty principle, which takes the form:

$$\sigma_A \sigma_B \ge \frac{1}{2}|\langle [A,B]\rangle|$$

note that the expectation value has to be taken with respect to some given state! if you plug in the $(1,0,0)$ vector you'll find $\langle[A,B]\rangle=0$, so the uncertainty principle only tells you that $\sigma_A\sigma_B\ge 0$. If you plug in $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,0,1)$ you won't, and the uncertainty relation will give you something more useful.